# i don't know what the expected expression is

Tags: objective-c, syntax-error

It says i have an error at the line `if ([validProduct.productIdentifier isEqualToString:SantaProductID]) {`. (Using Xcode 4.5)

It just says "Expected Expression".

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];
if (count>0) {
    validProducts = response.products;
    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([validProduct.productIdentifier isEqualToString:SantaProductID]) {
        [SantaLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"%@",validProduct.localizedTitle]];
        [SantaDescriptionLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                          @"%@",validProduct.localizedDescription]];
    }
```

Please help I thank everyone who answers in advance

Comment: What is `SantaProductID`?

Comment: `SantaProductID` probably isn't an instance of `NSString`.  Based on your code snippet, it probably doesn't exist at all.

Comment: I defined SantaProductID at the top of my code like this #define SantaProductID

Comment: `isEqualToString:` wants an NSString and not a preprocessor directive. Try: `NSString* SantaProductID = @"myID";`

Comment: If it helps i am trying to program in app purchases with this code

Comment: @0xfee1dead where do i put that code?

Comment: What are: `validProduct.productIdentifier` and `SantaProductID`? Type and Value. NSLog the and add the output to the question (copy/paste, don't re-type).

Comment: Note: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",validProduct.localizedTitle]` is not needed, just use: `validProduct.localizedTitle`. By convention method and variable names begin with a lowercase letter, class names begin with an Uppercase letter. Following that convention allows others to more easily understand your code.

Comment: @0xfee1dead where do i put the code that you gave me?

Comment: Please show the #define. If it is a string literal check that it includes the @ and doesn't have a ;

Comment: FYI - Apple won't accept an app made with Xcode 4.5. You need at least Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 is in beta now (which you should be using to be ready for iOS 8 next month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

i just replaced the "SantaProductID" with the bundle identifiers for my IAP. Thank you for all the help to those that were nice.

Answer (score 1):

What I am getting from the comments under your Question is that your code looks like:

```
#define SantaProductID

-(void) productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    // Using SantaProductID here as an NSString*
}
```

The Problem is that you used a [preprocessor directive](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) to declare a runtime variable.
That wont work. (more details on what you used in the link above)

Instead of just declaring a compile time option you need to either:

- `#define` with an actual value, making the preprocessor replace every occurence of "SantaProductID" with this literal
- or use an actual variable like this: `NSString* SantaProductID = @"myID";` This variable could be a member of your Class that handles the IAP or in global scope (disadvised).